# Get the vocabulary ID by term or node

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am going to check whether a term belongs to a designated vocabulary.

Which function is used to get vocabulary by term or node?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Drupal 6, if you know the taxonomy term ID, you can get the vocabulary ID by using the following code:

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
$vid = $term->vid;
```

If you have a node ID, then you can use the following code to get the vocabulary ID of all the taxonomy terms associated with the node using the following code:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$vids = array();

if (!empty($node->taxonomy)) {
  foreach ($node->taxonomy as $tid => $term) {
    $vids[] = $term->vid;
  }
}
```

In Drupal 7, the code would be the following:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$vid = $term->vid;
```

In Drupal 7, the node property `$node->taxonomy` doesn't exist anymore. Instead, there is `$node->field_<vocabulary_name>`, which is an array with two different structures.

- tags

  [image: screenshot]
- other taxonomy terms

  [image: screenshot]

Using [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), you would get the taxonomy terms in the language they would be displayed, or in the language whose code is passed as argument to the function.

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
```

`$node` contains the node object, and `$field_name` the name of the taxonomy term field.

`$items` contains a simplified array, compared to the array contained in `$node->field_<vocabulary_name>`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7 the above code should be like this:

```
 $tid = 18;
 $vid = db_query('SELECT vid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE tid = :tid', 
                  array(':tid' => $tid)
                )->fetchField();
 echo $vid;
```

See more examples at [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) drupal 7 function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the code below:

```
$tid = 18;    
$result = db_query("SELECT vid FROM {term_data} WHERE tid = %d", $tid);
$vid = db_result($result);
echo $vid;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 :

First load the term using termId as follows :

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
$term = Term::load($termId);
$vocabularyId = $term->getVocabularyId();
```