# call a modules function from preprocess_page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks, theming

I want to be able to call the current nodes taxonomy tree from page.tpl.php by using a function already in the taxonomy module. So far I've only been able to obtain the current nodes taxonomy id with:

```
$tid = $variables['node']->field_category['und'][0]['tid'];
```

I tried using: taxonomy_get_tree($tid);

but this only returns an empty array.

is there a way for me to use functions from other modules in _preprocess_page ?

full code:

```
function centro_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
     $tid = $variables['node']->field_category['und'][0]['tid'];
     $variables['taxTree'] = taxonomy_get_tree($tid);
 }
```

Comment: You are indeed using the function successfully. I don't understand what you want to ask.

Comment: Did you use `print_r($result)` to check the tree?

Comment: i used print_r(taxonomy_get_tree($tid)); but all i get is array(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a taxonomy id. However, `taxonomy_get_tree` needs a vocabulary id as parameter, according to the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7.x . That's probably why you are getting an empty array.

In order to be able to call taxonomy_get_tree, you would need to get the vocabulary id first:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$vid = $term->vid;
print_r(taxonomy_get_tree($vid));
```

(see [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/get-the-vocabulary-id-by-term-or-node) for more details about getting the vid from a tid).

Comment: thanks this works. I'm guessing $vid is what distinguishes between tags and other types of custom taxonomy

Comment: Yes, exactly. "Tags" (created by default when you install a Drupal site) is only one of the many vocabularies you can define. Each taxonomy term belongs to a vocabulary.